# How to check if a value exists in an array in an object array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in which extended address information (street name, zip code, house number, etc.). I need to check for the existence of a street, a house, and if they do not exist, display an error. The array is below:

```
const obj = {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "10",
        "short_name": "100",
        "types": [
          "street_number"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Engelsa street",
        "short_name": "Engelsa street",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Saint-Petersburg",
        "short_name": "SPB",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Russia",
        "short_name": "RU",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "194017",
        "short_name": "194017",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Engelsa street, 100, Saint-Petersburg, Russia, 194017",
  }
```

Comment: please add your code, some examle to search and the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-roentgen-nvi93?file=/src/App.js

Comment: please add all you have to the question.

Comment: Your question needs to be elaborated... *have an object in which extended address information* is not clear

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to check, but something like `obj.address_components.filter(a => a.types.includes("street_number"))` should work

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Yes, this is almost correct, I additionally replaced the "filter" on the "some" - ```obj.address_components.some((a) => a.types.includes("street_number"))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the address components array for *some* element entry that has a `types` array with *every* value you want it to contain.

```
obj.address_components.some(({ types }) =>
  types.every((type) => [/* list of keys */].includes(type))
);
```

```js
const obj = {
    address_components: [
      {
        long_name: "10",
        short_name: "100",
        types: ["street_number"]
      },
      {
        long_name: "Engelsa street",
        short_name: "Engelsa street",
        types: ["route"]
      },
      {
        long_name: "Saint-Petersburg",
        short_name: "SPB",
        types: ["locality", "political"]
      },
      {
        long_name: "Russia",
        short_name: "RU",
        types: ["country", "political"]
      },
      {
        long_name: "194017",
        short_name: "194017",
        types: ["postal_code"]
      }
    ],
    formatted_address: "Engelsa street, 100, Saint-Petersburg, Russia, 194017"
  };

const res = obj.address_components.some(({ types }) => types.every(type => ['country', 'locality'].includes(type)));
const res2 = obj.address_components.some(({ types }) => types.every(type => ['country', 'political'].includes(type)));

console.log("'country', 'locality'", res);
console.log("'country', 'political'", res2);
```

If you want to search that *every* key term is included by *some* element then use:

```
[/* list of keys */].every((key) =>
  obj.address_components.some(({ types }) => types.includes(key))
);
```

```js
const obj = {
  address_components: [
    {
      long_name: "10",
      short_name: "100",
      types: ["street_number"]
    },
    {
      long_name: "Engelsa street",
      short_name: "Engelsa street",
      types: ["route"]
    },
    {
      long_name: "Saint-Petersburg",
      short_name: "SPB",
      types: ["locality", "political"]
    },
    {
      long_name: "Russia",
      short_name: "RU",
      types: ["country", "political"]
    },
    {
      long_name: "194017",
      short_name: "194017",
      types: ["postal_code"]
    }
  ],
  formatted_address: "Engelsa street, 100, Saint-Petersburg, Russia, 194017"
};

const res = ["country", "locality"].every((key) =>
  obj.address_components.some(({ types }) => types.includes(key))
);

console.log("'country', 'locality'", res);
console.log("'country', 'locality', 'city'", ["country", "locality", "city"].every((key) =>
  obj.address_components.some(({ types }) => types.includes(key))
));
```

Comment: Thank you! Another shorter option ```obj.address_components.some((a) => a.types.includes("street_number"))```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a function where you pass in the required values and then reduce the types to a single array. From there you loop over your required values to ensure they are in the actual values:

```js
const obj = {
  "address_components": [{
      "long_name": "10",
      "short_name": "100",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Engelsa street",
      "short_name": "Engelsa street",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Saint-Petersburg",
      "short_name": "SPB",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Russia",
      "short_name": "RU",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "194017",
      "short_name": "194017",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address": "Engelsa street, 100, Saint-Petersburg, Russia, 194017",
};

function isValidAddress(obj, requiredFields) {
  // reduce to array of types ['street_number', 'political', ...etc]
  const actualFields = obj.address_components.reduce((acc, { types }) => {
    acc.push(...types);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  let valid = true;
  // loop through the smaller requiredFields to see if its included in the actual
  requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
    valid = valid && actualFields.includes(field);
  });
  
  return valid;
}

const requiredFields = ['street_number', 'route'];


console.log(isValidAddress(obj, requiredFields));
```